React router V6: how to have two simultaneous and independent navigation outlets
I am building a website with a 2 parts (let's call them left and right) and on each part there is tabs.
Something like this :

What I would like to have is an URL like this :
"https://mywebsite?right=billing&left=stock"
where 'left=' and 'right=' are used to find the content to display.
Simplified App structure
I have a Split component where there is PanelLeft and PanelRight children components:
App.tsx
<Split
  sizes={60, 40}
  direction="horizontal"
>
  <PanelLeft />
  <PanelRight />
</Split>

const PanelLeft = () => {
  const leftPart: string = extractQueryFromUrl('left') // give me 'stock'
  return <Outlet context={{ leftPart }} />;
};

const PanelRight= () => {
  const rightPart: string = extractQueryFromUrl('right') // give me 'billing'
  return <Outlet context={{ rightPart }} />;
};

main.tsx
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App/>,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        element: <PanelLeft />,
        children: generateChildRoutes(),
      },
      {
        path: "",
        element: <PanelRight />,
        children: generateChildRoutes(),
      },
    ],
  },
]);

const generateChildRoutes = () => [
  { path: "/", element: <Home /> },
  { path: "stock", element: <Stock /> },
  { path: "billing", element: <Billing /> },
];

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router}>
  </RouterProvider>
);

Obviously, the mapping in createBrowserRouter and the <Outlet context={{leftPart}}/> are not working at all.
I wonder how could I configure them to be able to get the two independent navigation panel.
Note: The real app is much more complicated, use redux to retrieve states based on unique tabId etc... It is working very well with one Outlet and for instance two sub routes (https://mywebsite/panelright/billing and https://mywebsite/panelleft/billing) so the issue is really for simultaneous independent display.
EDIT (22/09/2024)
Thank you both @Drew Reese and @Matthew for your time and explanations. You were right that having multiple Outlets makes no sense and will never work as intended. I ended up with a solution close to Matthew's suggestion with one outlet and direct use on the other.
something like this
export const tabsRoutesMap: Map<string, JSX.Element> = new Map([
    [Billing_Path, <Billing />],
    [Stock_Path, <Stock/>],
//... others possible tabs...
]);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <App/>,
        // generate children from tabs route
        children: Array.from(tabsRoutesMap, ([path, element]) => ({ path, element })),
    
    },
]);

And then :
<>
    {tabsRoutesMap.get(extractedPathFromUrl)}
</>


Why are you building your site this way? Is this idle curiosity or another problem that you are trying to solve?

@KartikMudgal - Requested usage are : Users should be able to navigate on left panel, open tabs on it but at any given time, move it to the right panel in a new tab to be saved. This is mainly used for data  comparison or multi-tasking. Any tab should be able to be set either on left or right.

If you want to make it with createBrowserRouter you can do it with outlet as right component and left component is normal.
const Layout = ({ Component }) => (
  <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
    <div className="box">
      <h2>Left Section</h2>
      <Component />
    </div>
    <div className="box">
      <h2>Right Section</h2>
      <Outlet context="right" />
    </div>
  </div>
);

const children = () => {
  return [
    { path: "1", element: <Component1 /> },
    { path: "2", element: <Component2 /> },
    { path: "3", element: <Component3 /> },
  ];
};

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <RoutesExample />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "1",
        element: <Layout Component={Component1} />,
        children: children(),
      },
      {
        path: "2",
        element: <Layout Component={Component2} />,
        children: children(),
      },
      {
        path: "3",
        element: <Layout Component={Component3} />,
        children: children(),
      },
    ],
  },
]);

Demo
and if you want to use url params here is a simple solution
const Table = () => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const left = searchParams.get("left");
  const right = searchParams.get("right");
  ComponentLeft = componentList[left];
  ComponentRight = componentList[right];
  return left && right ? (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <div className="box">
        <h2>Left Section</h2>
        <ComponentLeft />
      </div>
      <div className="box">
        <h2>Right Section</h2>
        <ComponentRight />
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div></div>
  );
};

where
const Component1 = () => {
  return <div>1</div>;
};
const Component2 = () => {
  return <div>2</div>;
};
const Component3 = () => {
  return <div>3</div>;
};

const componentList = {
  1: Component1,
  2: Component2,
  3: Component3,
};

Demo

The problem is that you have a browser and there is only one URL path to match and synchronize a route to, so it makes no sense to have more than one Outlet at any given depth because only one route can be matched and rendered.
If you want/need to independent routers/outlets/etc then you'll very likely need a very "hands-on"/manual solution.
Here's a Proof of Concept using two sibling MemoryRouter components, one in each "panel", that read the current window.location.search to synchronize each panel's router to that panel's value.
Example:
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const PanelLayout = ({ panel }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // Get current "global" URL search params
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

  // Get current panel's search value
  const target = searchParams.get(panel) ?? "";
  
  // Synchronize the panel's MemoryRouter to current target panel path
  useEffect(() => {
    navigate(`/${target}`, { replace: true });
  }, [target]);

  return (
    <>
      ...
      <Outlet />
      ...
    </>
  );
};

const generateChildRoutes = (panel) => [
  {
    element: <PanelLayout panel={panel} />,
    children: [
      { path: "/", element: <Home /> },
      { path: "stock", element: <Stock /> },
      { path: "billing", element: <Billing /> },
    ],
  },
];

const leftRouter = useMemo(
  () => createMemoryRouter(generateChildRoutes("left")),
  []
);
const rightRouter = useMemo(
  () => createMemoryRouter(generateChildRoutes("right")),
  []
);

...

<Split
  sizes={ 60, 40 }
  direction="horizontal"
>
  <PanelLeft>
    <RouterProvider router={leftRouter} />
  </PanelLeft>

  <PanelRight>
    <RouterProvider router={rightRouter} />
  </PanelRight>
</Split>

Main - You can't nest routers, so the root BrowserRouter will be eliminated.
createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <App />
);

Demo




Left
Right
Example




home
home



stock
home



stock
billing



home
billing




